# Elegant way to concat lists and elements into vector

Tags: clojure

Is there a more concise and/or elegant way to express the last line in the let.

```
(let [a ... ; int
      b ... ; int
      xs ... ; list
      y ... ; int
      z ... ; int
      ]
  (into [a b] cat [xs [y z]]))
```

The result should be a vector. The expression above looks rather complicated for the simple task it accomplishes. In Python this would be
`[a, b] + xs + [y,z]` which better captures the similarity of the two append operations.  A variant that is longer that would capture that similarity is

```
(into [] cat [[a b] xs [y z]])
```

My attempts at using `concat` seems verbose, but perhaps more readable?

```
(vec (concat [a b] xs [y z]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

into/cat would definitely be the most popular approach. If you are dying for concision, you can instead use syntax-quote, the power tool for building lists:

```
`[~a ~b ~@xs ~y ~z]
```

It's very expressive and it works, but it will surely be slower: it is designed primarily for use at compile time with small inputs. The overhead is pretty small, though; you can see what code this will expand to by quoting it:

```
user=> '`[~a ~b ~@xs ~y ~z]
(apply vector 
       (seq (concat (list a)
                    (list b)
                    xs
                    (list y)
                    (list z))))
```

I've edited the output to make it more readable, by removing the `clojure.core/` prefix and adding whitespace, but semantically this is what the REPL printed.

Comment: Very creative!  Didn't think of it despite using macros fairly often.  `macroexpand-all` does show some overhead, as you warned.

Comment: `macroexpand-all` is irrelevant here. You can just quote it. But there's less overhead than I expected. Almost none, really, just using four separate lists for a/b/x/y instead of the two lists ab/xy.

Comment: `macroexpand-all` gives me fully expanded expression at end of compile which I use to analyze runtime cost, which is all I care about.  Is that a mistake?  The overhead I was referring to was the new list for each non-seq element.  As you mentioned, not too bad.

Comment: But there's no macro to expand at all. I've edited the answer to show that quoting is all you need to do, to see what happens.

Comment: Got it!  The expansion is done by the reader.  https://clojure.org/reference/reader#syntax-quote

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what's in your `...`s. Maybe you would prefer to move some of the verbosity to the `let`? Sometimes complex lines are a sign that the functions providing your inputs could be helped by smaller, intermediary functions. Here, for example, you'd have functions `get-ab` and `get-yz` that return `[a b]` and `[y z]`, respectively.

```
(let [ab (get-ab) ; list
      xs ... ; list
      yz ... (get-yz)] ; list
  (into [] cat [ab xs yz]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow!  How many years have passed and I never realized [the transducer `cat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cat) had been added to the language.  I thought at first you had some Python-esque pseudo-code there.

A concrete example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))  ; <= *** many helper functions! ***

(dotest
  (let [a  1 ; int
        b  2 ; int
        xs [:x1 :x2 :x3] ; list
        y  25 ; int
        z  26 ; int
        ]
    (spyx (into [a b] cat [xs [y z]]))))
```

which prints:

```
(into [a b] cat [xs [y z]]) => [1 2 :x1 :x2 :x3 25 26]
```

Re your question, for smallish sizes `concat` seems a perfectly good answer:

```
(concat [a b] xs [y z]) => (1 2 :x1 :x2 :x3 25 26)  ; A lazy sequence
```

although you should be aware of [The Ticking Time-Bomb](https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat) for larger sequences.  If you want simplicity and don't need laziness, I have written the `glue` function in [the Tupelo Clojure library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#gluing-together-like-collections):

```
; Glue together like collections:
(is (= (glue [ 1 2] '(3 4) [ 5 6] )       [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]  ))   ; all sequential (vectors & lists)
(is (= (glue {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3} )       {:a 1 :c 3 :b 2} ))   ; all maps
(is (= (glue #{1 2} #{3 4} #{6 5} )      #{ 1 2 6 5 3 4 }  ))   ; all sets
(is (= (glue "I" " like " \a " nap!" )   "I like a nap!"   ))   ; all text (strings & chars)

; If you want to convert to a sorted set or map, just put an empty one first:
(is (= (glue (sorted-map) {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3})   {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} ))
(is (= (glue (sorted-set) #{1 2} #{3 4} #{6 5})  #{ 1 2 3 4 5 6  } ))
```

Another answer is similar to the idea of using `syntax-quote`, using [->vector](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.190/api/tupelo.core#-%3Evector) and [unwrap](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.190/api/tupelo.core#unwrap)
:

```
(->vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)             =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
(->vector 1 (unwrap [2 3 4 5 6 7 8]) 9)  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

It will also work recursively for nested unwrap calls:

```
(->vector 1 (unwrap [2 3 (unwrap [4 5 6]) 7 8]) 9)  =>  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

If the scalar values are only at the beginning or end, I would suggest [using `prepend` and `append`](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#adding-values-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-sequence):

```
(append [1 2] 3  )   ;=> [1 2 3  ]
(append [1 2] 3 4)   ;=> [1 2 3 4]

(prepend   3 [2 1])  ;=> [  3 2 1]
(prepend 4 3 [2 1])  ;=> [4 3 2 1]
```

Of course, if you don't need to retain any nested structure in the 5 things you are combining, perhaps the Big Sledgehammer (tm) is the easiest:

```
(flatten [[a b] xs [y z]]) => (1 2 :x1 :x2 :x3 25 26)
```

---

As always, ***don't forget*** to study [the Clojure CheatSheet!](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet)

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify that `->vector`, `append`, and `prepend` are from Tupelo, while `flatten` is standard?  Kudos on your open source contributions to the community!

Comment: Added some links.